# How to present a collection of objects in a listbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I have a collection of objects that I want to present. How can I do this? A listbox would do but each object has many attributes which I want to present. I already bound a listbox to a collection and I have all my objects listed. My question is regarding the visualization of the listbox and if the listbox is the correct thing to use or there is something else that I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) control instead. `ListView` has support for columns if you are planning on showing several properties from your object. You can use the `ItemTemplate` property to format the display of your object. For example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myObjectCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShouldCheck}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This example assumes that your object has the properties `Title` and `ShouldCheck`.

Comment: Setting the ItemTemplate is the way to go if you use a ListBox but certainly not when you use a ListView. ListViews have a view functionality, hence the name, if templates are to be employed they should be within the `ListView.View`. Also saying that ListViews support columns is very inaccurate, `GridViews` support columns, the ListView only supports Views in general. Further your code does not work like you posted it, you probably meant to wrap the contents of the DataTemplate in a StackPanel.

Answer (score 2):

I find the existing answers to be a bit lacking, normally one would not process collections or boil their items down to a string, at the very best you would do some dynamic manipulation using a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) (e.g. sorting, grouping), but normally you use [**Data Templating**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) to display the individual items which allows you to use all their properties.

Further there are several controls which work well with collections, firstly you need to know if you want selection, if not an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) is a good choice, otherwise you should use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) or [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx).

ListViews are normally employed if you have different views for your objects, e.g. a details view and a thumbnail view. You can use the [`ListView.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx) for this, there is one existing view in the framework, the [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx), which offers columns. What Matthew Ferreira suggested is exactly what you should not do with a ListView since you want to make the templates dependent on the current view, in fact that code does not even compile since `DataTemplate` can only have one child.

ListViews are supposed to encapsulate the view logic in their view so it can be changed at will. If you decide to use a `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` then setting the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) is what you want to do. Read the Data Templating overview i linked to, it makes for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection of object is probably to be viewed as your model. The usual thing in WPF is to add a *ViewModel* that translates and exposes the model data into a form suitable for binding. Depending on what you want to do, your VM could e.g. format each object into a string representation and then expose it as a collection of strings that the Listbox can bind to and display.

Comment: This ViewModel is a WPF thing or is it a general term to explain to me what I have to do. If so, I understood what you mean but the way to do it, is just formatting the listbox items with a template?

Comment: Model-View-ViewModel is the recommended design pattern to use in WPF with the two-way databinding. It neatly separates the GUI, the data storage/retrieval including business rules and the data formatting/manipulation logic.

Comment: While using MVVM is a good idea, transforming the items in a collection into strings just so the ListBox can display it is not. It wastes space and is a lot more complicated than applying some data-templating or bindings with `StringFormat`. In the worst case one could employ a `ValueConverter` but creating a duplicate collection should never be an option.